# Which probability inequality is applied in this proof?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

I'm trying to understand which probability inequality is used at the end of the following proof of Kingman's theorem in Revuz' *Markov Chains* book. He's considering a probability space with probability measure $m$ and a $m$-preserving (i.e. $m\circ\theta^{-1}=m$) measurable $\theta$.

[image]
[image]
[image]

It looks like Markov's inequality but this would yield $\le\varepsilon^{-1}\int\sup_{0\le r<k}s_k\:{\rm d}m\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\frac1n$, where $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\frac1n=\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that the [Layer-Cake Representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_cake_representation) will allow us to write
$$\int \sup_{0 \leq r < k} s_r dm = \int_0^\infty m(\sup_{0 \leq r < k} s_r > t) dt$$
since $s_r$ is assumed to be positive.

Now by a change of variables, you get that
\begin{align*}
\int \sup_{0 \leq r < k} s_r dm =& \varepsilon \int_0^\infty m(\sup_{0 \leq r < k} s_r > \varepsilon s) ds
\\
\geq & \varepsilon \int_0^\infty m(\sup_{0 \leq r < k} s_r > \varepsilon \operatorname{ceil}(s)) ds
\\
=& \varepsilon \sum_{n=1}^\infty m(\sup_{0 \leq r < k} s_r > \varepsilon n)
\end{align*}
which rearranges to the desired inequality.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you see how this yields the subsequent inequality for $\limsup\frac{s_n}n$? I mean what you've shown in your answer yields that the second term in the previous inequality almost surely converges to $0$, but why does the first term converge to $\operatorname E\left[T^ks_k/k\mid\mathcal I\right]$ (which is equal to $\operatorname E\left[s_k/k\mid\mathcal I\right]$)?

Comment: I'd still be interested in the question from in my last comment. (I've uploaded the relevant four pages here https://www.docdroid.net/AV3Jjg0/revuz-pdf.)

Comment: @0xbadf00d I don't do any Ergodic Theory stuff so I probably don't have enough knowledge of the relevant context but that does kind of look like it should just be Birkhoff's ergodic theorem?

Comment: But how does it need to be applied? Please take a look at this question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3650551/47771.